# No getdate() function in EnterpriseDB PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, enterprisedb

Do you have any idea on how to have a `getdate()` function in EnterpriseDB PostgreSQL? I upgraded to EDB-PSQL, and when I try to restore old data from the free PSQL, it returns error on some tables since there is no `getdate()`.

I believe this should automatically be created upon creating new database? But it didn't. :( Only a `now()` function.

Can I create the function instead? Help!

Comment: I can't find a function called "getdate" in my installations or in the Postgres documentation. Do you have idea where it has come from in your DB? Try to dump the whole DB in question instead of particular tables.

Comment: Try this: select * from pg_function where funname = 'getdate';
Its from my old database.

Comment: I don't remember a function called getdate() either, nor is there a catalogue called 'pg_function'. Which PostgreSQL version where you using?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If `getdate()` is like `now()` (as with SQL Server) you can simply say

```
create function public.getdate() returns timestamptz
       stable language sql as 'select now()';
```